# Integrating sharepoint with lightbox

Tags: sharepoint

I want to integrate lightbox video with sharepoint. I have a site that I am migrating to sharepoint and I want the lightbox plugin to integrate with sharepoint. Could anyone tell me how to achieve this.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks,
Prakash

Comment: Light box jQuery Plugin that is what you are talking about ? Can you share the Link of the Plugin.

Comment: I believe you actually want to have your videos stored in sharepoint to play in the lightbox when they are clicked, that takes some integration coding to achieve, be on the client or the server. Give us more detail as Kusek said and you can get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

All I have is the Url of the videos yah they are on the server.My requirement is to play these videos using lighbox.Actually videos are already running on the site using lightbox but we are migrating that site to sharepoint.So they have a list where all the links of the videos are present.

I found this link
http://videobox-lb.sourceforge.net/

and I have put all the js files and css files in document library and I am referring these js and css files in page layout page but I don't know its not working when I m clicking on the link its going to the Url instead of opening there only like lightbox does.